# GSX 1000 Issues Upon Reboot

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa

I have my Sennheiser GSX 1000 External DAC/AMP setup through editing the pulseaudio config. I can run the command "aplay -1" and I can see my GSX on devices 1,0 and 1,1 but when I reboot the system and run the command again the devices move to 3,0 and 3,1 causing pulseaudio to break. I can run "alsa force-reload" and my GSX is back to devices 1,0 and 1,1 so I have sound again. Can anyone tell me why my GSX is changing device card id when rebooting and what to do to stop it?

Comment: Other sound devices got that number first. What other devices do you have?

Comment: The two front and back audio jacks on my PC, the audio jack that's integrated into a usb 3.0 hub I have plugged in and the HDMI audio devices for both my 760 and R9 390.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the system is booted, the first sound card number is assigned to the first driver that happens to report that a device has been found.

To prevent other drivers from getting the first two numbers, add the following to some `.conf` file in `/etc/modprobe.d/`:

```
options snd slots=snd-usb-audio,snd-usb-audio
```

To fix the order of the two USB audio devices, add the following line:

```
options snd-usb-audio index=0,1 vid=0xAAAA,0xCCCC pid=0xBBBB,0xDDDD
```

where `AAAA`…`DDDD` can be found in the output of `lsusb`:

```
$ lsusb
Bus *** Device ***: ID ****:**** Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus *** Device ***: ID AAAA:BBBB The Hub Audio Thingy
Bus *** Device ***: ID CCCC:DDDD Sennheiser GSX 1000
Bus *** Device ***: ID ****:**** USB Toaster
...
```

See https://alsa.opensrc.org/MultipleUSBAudioDevices for a longer explanation.